# Action stopped message during Form Data Event in SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

I make some validations in Form Data Event on Update data button and
I set the `bubbleEvent` to `false` when validation returns `false`.

I am getting the error on Form data event:

```
Action stopped by add-on (UI_API -7780)  [Message 66000-152]
```

Is there any suggestions how to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue, this is the intended functionality. If you don't want the user to get the error, just catch that Exception message and suppress it.

Comment: That's what i'm doing now but I don't think that this is a good solution because when I catch the Exception message and suppress it the pip sound is appear and the user can't understand what's happening at that moment. So I'm looking for more valuable solution.